# Invalid Modelica model works fine when instantiated in another model. Why?

Tags: instantiation, modelica

I have 2 Modelica models:

```
model parent
  child dingus;
equation 
  dingus.a = 37;
  dingus.c = 666;
end parent;
```

and

```
model child
  Real a;
  Real b;
  Real c;
equation 
  a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 1;
end child;
```

When I check the code, `parent` checks out okay, but `child` gives errors about the mismatch of unknowns and equations, as expected.  Why does it work in `parent`, and is there a cleaner, best practice way of implementing this?  I want to use child in multiple different parents, and I may want to change how I interface with it so I don't want to overly define it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it should be clear that `child` is not balanced since, as you point out, it doesn't have the same number of equations as unknowns.  The `parent` model is ok since it does have the same number of equations as unknowns.  It gets one equation from `child` and provides two of its own.  Since there are exactly three variables `child.a`, `child.b` and `child.c`, the whole thing is balanced.

But the bigger picture issue (which I think is what you are trying to get at) is how to avoid issues where `child` looks like a "bad" model.  A simple solution is:

```
model child
  input Real a;
  output Real b;
  input Real c;
equation 
  a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 1;
end child;
```

This conveys the idea that values for `a` and `c` will come from "outside" somewhere.

To anticipate your next question..."But what happens in cases when I want to specify `b` and `c` and solve for `a`?  Surely I don't have to write another model with the same equations and variables but with the `input` and `output` qualifiers on different variables?"

You can use the above model without issues.  The reason is that the `input` and `output` qualifiers only restrict how things are **connected**.  We aren't actually making any connections, so we are ok.  So you can provide equations for an `output` and solve for an `input`.  While it may seem a little counter intuitive, that is perfectly legal in Modelica.  The reason that `input` and `output` are useful here is that they implicitly specify how many equations we expect this model itself to provide (the outputs) and how many we expect to come from outside (the inputs).  But they don't (and can't) restrict which variables we provide explicit equations for.

One final note, I suggest you add the equations for an instance of `child` in the declaration.  I seem to recall there were some special rules in Modelica for handling this when determining whether something is balanced.  So as far as I recall, the correct way to approach this would be:

```
model child
  input Real a;
  input Real b;
  output Real c; // A bit arbitrary which one is output
equation 
  a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 1;
end child;

model parent
  child dingus(a=37, c=666);
end parent;
```

In this way, you can treat `child` as what amounts to a "named equation".  Even better, you can make it `replaceable` which allows you to swap it for others.  A typically application of this would be to substitute one equation of state for another or one equilibrium condition for another.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Excellent.  That works pretty much exactly how I would want it to work with the input and output modifiers.  However, I now realize that squaring each term was a bad idea for demonstration purposes because it is really easy to pick a value for the input variable that renders a solution impossible.

Comment: When I specify the value of c in the declaration of child, I still get 2 warnings:
"May only set inputs, parameters, and variables with default, but modified c."
"The following input lacks a binding equation:
dingus.b"

Warnings are certainly preferable to errors, but if there's a way to get rid of the warnings, that would be ideal.

Comment: So I guess it does matter which signals are marked with `input`.  I suspect there is some work around for this (since I think this pattern is used in the media/fluid library), but I don't recall what it is.